# Rails scope check serialize column is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I am learning the scope of rails

if QuestionSet has a column called questions_list and its format is `serialize`.

Like this

```
class QuestionSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :questions_list
end
```

Then I have a method called `is_order`, and it is simple.
The only use is to check whether questions_list is present or not

Like this

```
def is_order
  self.questions_list.present?
end
```

Can I write it into a scope? Or in this case, it is not a suitable scope scenario

Comment: Ruby convention is to name a method that returns a boolean value with a question mark at the end, so `def is_order?` instead of `def is_order`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a scope that will return QuestionSet records that have a questions_list present, you should be able to define a scope like this:

```
scope :with_questions_list, -> { where.not(questions_list: nil) }
```

And then you can do:

```
QuestionSet.with_questions_list # This is the same as QuestionSet.all.with_questions_list
```

If the goal is instead to build a method that will return `true` or `false` for a single object, then you are doing it correctly, but I'll suggest two changes: (1) You don't need to reference `self` (as that is implied in the context) and (2) you should use the Ruby convention of putting a question mark at the end of your method.

```
def is_order?
  questions_list.present?
end
```

Comment: No, my goal is to return a boolean value from an instance of `QuestionSet`'
like `q = QuestionSet.last`, `q.is_order => true`, I can achieve it with a method, I was just wondering how to make it by `scope`

Comment: OK, but that's not a scope. A scope is a class method that is called on an ActiveRecord collection, not a single object.

Comment: you can omit `all`, its unnecessary here.

Comment: Agreed, but I thought it would be more clear to the OP.

Comment: Thanks, you can update your answer with explanation, and I will pick you as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

`scope` is a wrong choice here, becuase it's always returns an **Active Record** and doesn't bound to any instance object, `scope` it's about collection.

> Scoping allows you to specify commonly-used queries which can be
>   referenced as method calls on the association objects or models.